# Como percorrer todas colunas de uma table com jquery e ocultar se for vazia

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma **table html** com 15 linhas e preciso percorrer todas as colunas e verificar se existe algum valor, se **Coluna for igual a vazia então oculto** essa coluna, sei que esse exemplo abaixo oculta a coluna posição 5, mas como percorrer as colunas ?.

```
$('#btnBuscar').on('click', function () {

    //Percorro todas as colunas
    //Se coluna vazia então oculto essa coluna

    $('.grid td:nth-child(5), th:nth-child(5)').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa percorrer a table usando $.each, e adicionar um marcador para ter o controle dos elementos que serão excluídos, exemplo...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ocultar').on('click', function(){
   var i = 1;
   $('table.click tr td').each(function(el){
    
     if($(this).text() == '') {
      
       $('table.click td:nth-child('+i+'), th:nth-child('+i+')').hide(); 
        
        }
        
        i++;
      
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="click">

<tr>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>teste1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>teste3</td>
  <td>teste4</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>teste6</td>
  <td>teste7</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>teste9</td>
  <td>teste10</td>
  
</tr>

</table>
<button class="ocultar">
Ocultar
</button>
```

Comment: Olá @Felipe Duarte funciona, porém o botão `btnBuscar` faz um `submit` na `view` a fim de carregar os dados do Cliente, no entanto a função que oculta as colunas é executado **antes**, ou seja eu **oculto** e na sequencia é feito um **refresh** na table, pois uso o mesmo botão que faz o submit eu preciso ocultar as colunas depois da table tiver sido totalmente carregada, tem como contornar isso ?

Comment: resolvido, coloquei o código no final do script e funcionou!

Comment: me ocorreu uma outra dúvida relacionada com esse post e caso você puder me auxiliar eu agradeço (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213481/percorrer-todas-as-linhas-de-um-table-html-e-ocultar-caso-alguma-coluna-5-seja-v)