# Percorrer todas as linhas de um table Html e ocultar caso alguma coluna 5 seja vazia

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Não tenho conhecimento avançado com jquery e preciso percorrer todas as linhas de um table Html e ocultar a Linha **inteira** caso a coluna **a partir** da número **5 (JUS)** seja vazia e atualizar a numeração sequencia da primeira coluna **Id**, exemplo:

Quero ocultar a linha inteira caso a 5 e 6 (e demais se houver 7,8,n...) coluna seja vazia:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que fique assim:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisei ocultar as colunas e usei o código abaixo sugerido e aceito pelo [Felipe Duarte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/50820/felipe-duarte) nesse post [Como percorrer todas colunas de uma table com jquery e ocultar se for vazia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213463/como-percorrer-todas-colunas-de-uma-table-com-jquery-e-ocultar-se-for-vazia/213464#213464)

```
var i = 1;
$('table.grid tr td').each(function (el) {
    if ($(this).text() == '') {
          $('table.grid td:nth-child(' + i + '), th:nth-child(' + i + ')').hide();
    }
    i++;
})
```

Essa é a estrutura atual da minha table:

```
<table class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="head">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>PAR</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>JUS</th>
            <th>ST</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">1 </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>A3</td>
            <td>A4</td>
            <td>A5</td>
            <td>A6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>B2</td>
            <td>B3</td>
            <td>B4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>B6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C1</td>
            <td>C2</td>
            <td>C3</td>
            <td>C4</td>
            <td>C5</td>
            <td>C6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ao invés de manipular o DOM para fazer isso, não pensou em fazer essa verificação no back-end e enviar somente a lista que deverá ser populada na tabela?

Comment: Sim, mas no momento não é viável tenho que fazer algo manipulando o DOM.

Comment: Entendi @AdrianoSUV, é que um filter no end-point resolveria bem mais perfomático e elegante, ou até no recebimento dos dados no front (caso a requisição for ajax) - ambas as formas não precisariam remontar a tabela depois de criada.

Comment: @Lucas Costa vou levar em consideração essa alternativa também é que o meu problema é que preciso está com isso funcionando perfeitamente hoje! rs To numa suadeira!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um exemplo minimo é criar uma função que consigo ler as `tr` dessa tabela e encontrar na coluna especifica se a mesma não tem nenhum valor.

```js
function ocultar() {
  var table = $('table.grid');
  var i = 0;
  table.find('tr').next('tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').eq(4).text() == '') {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {      
        $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(++i);      
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   // se quiser que fique dinamico descomente aqui.
  //ocultar();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="grid" border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>EMPRESA</td>
    <td>PAR</td>
    <td>DATA</td>
    <td>JUS</td>
    <td>ST</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>A4</td>
    <td>A5</td>
    <td>A6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <td>B4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>B6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>C5</td>
    <td>C6</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="ocultar()">Ocultar</button>
```

---

Com `tbody`:

```js
function ocultar() {
  var table = $('table.grid');
  var i = 0;
  table.find('tbody > tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').eq(4).text() == '') {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {     
        $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(++i);
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  // se quiser que fique dinamico descomente aqui.
  //ocultar();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="grid" border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>EMPRESA</td>
    <td>PAR</td>
    <td>DATA</td>
    <td>JUS</td>
    <td>ST</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td>A2</td>
      <td>A3</td>
      <td>A4</td>
      <td>A5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>B1</td>
      <td>B2</td>
      <td>B3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>B5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
      <td>C4</td>
      <td>C5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<button onclick="ocultar()">Ocultar</button>
```

---

A outra forma seria você já trazer esses dados prontos do seu `Controller`, acredito ainda ser a melhor opção. Como não consta a sua parte de codigo, não tenho como reproduzir um exemplo ...

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [jQuery - .find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [jQuery - .next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [jQuery - .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [jQuery - .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [jQuery - .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: Olá @Virgilio Novic preciso manipular o DOM devido ao cenário atual, no momento dá pra fazer no Controller.

Comment: Então @AdrianoSUV a minha resposta está com manipulação de `Dom` de uma olhada fiz até uma nova edição.

Comment: @Vigilio Novic ocorreu esse erro: `Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined` tentei alterar o `innerHTML` para `text` mas ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Vou ver a nova edição

Comment: Não ocorre mais erro, vou testar e respondo aqui caso estiver ok.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV o exemplo é para você entender o processo e colocar na sua, como você não colocou na sua pergunta a tabela pode ter que adaptar o código, porque você pode perceber que na resposta está funcionando...

Comment: Sim com certeza! estou implementando

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente baseado na tabela de exemplo mas na estrutura da minha tabela não tá funcionando. Pelo que entendi  se houver pelo menos uma célula vazia todas as linhas são ocultadas. minha table tem tags `thead`,  `tfoot`  e  `tbody`  já tentei manipular o script mas tenho um pouco de dificuldade vou editar o post e incluir a minha `table` eu agradeço desde já.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV editado com a tag `tbody`!!! duas opções ...